# Pandas groupby to find mean count of categorical field

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Working with a pandas dataframe, trying to get the mean count of one field grouped by another. I have the below dataframe

```
user_id    tag_number
----------------------
1             xx
1             xx
1             xy
2             xy
2             zz
2             zz
2             zz
```

I am trying to get the average `tag_number` counts per unique `tag_number` grouped by `user_id`. I can do `data.groupby(["user_id", "tag_number"]).size()`
to get the following result

```
user_id  tag_number
-------------------------
1        xx            2
         xy            1
2        xy            1
         zz            3
```

but what i am looking for is

```
user_id   avg_tag_number_count
------------------------------
1          1.5

2          2.0
```

because for user 1 there are a total of 3 tag_number instances between 2 unique tag_numbers. And for user 2 there are a total of 4 tag_number instances between 2 unique tag_numbers.

Comment: You are almost there: `data.groupby(["user_id", "tag_number"]).size().mean(level=0)`

Comment: @QuangHoang This won't work.

Comment: @MayankPorwal updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

```
data.groupby(["user_id", "tag_number"]).size().groupby(level=0).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'avg_tag_number_count'})
```

Output:

```
   user_id  avg_tag_number_count
0        1                   1.5
1        2                   2.0
```